# Download and install exe file present at maven artifactory on AWS using system manager run command

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

We have a use case where the common software which needs to be installed on each instance in AWS are present at Maven artifactory. A central team ensures that the latest version is present at the artifactory and each individual team has to ensure that they download the latest version or upgrade the existing version on their instances.

So things to achieve
- Download the file/exe from AWS if the local installation is outdated or not present
- Install/upgrade the file/exe on the local instances

Current plan is to use AWS system manager (state manager for the same)

The file download can work using curl but i am trying to do the same with powershell.

Tried using Get-Item but it gives an error saying not able to find directory https which is the part of url provided for maven location

used curl -O -J -L  and it works locally

Expectation or use case mentioned above. 
Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What the exact command you tried with PowerShell?

Comment: Tried Get-Item, Copy-Item and Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://<username>:<password>@maven.<path>/<filename.exe>" -Outfile "C:\temp" -Credential "username"

Comment: What is the error message when you run Invoke-WebRequest? If you run this Invoke-WebRequest "https://<domain>/filename.exe" -outfile c:\temp\filename.exe <-- it will work. Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6 The -OutFile will require path+filename. If C:\temp is missing there is different error

Answer (score 0):

$downloadSource = "https://XXXXXX"

$downloadDest = "C:\XXXXX"

$username = "XXXXX"

$passwordPlain = "XXXXX"

## Convert to secure password and build credentials object

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $passwordPlain -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

## Download the file

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $downloadSource -OutFile $downloadDest -Credential $credentials

The above command or .sh file will be able to connect to the URL with the provided username and password and will be able to download the file at the  path mentioned